# How do I stop a script on a Raspberry Pi Pico?

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

On a Raspberry Pi Pico I ran a looping script that blinks the onboard LED. It loops forever.

I can’t reset it, stopping the power doesn’t work because it runs on startup and Thonny doesn’t even recognize the Raspberry Pi Pico isn't connected anymore. I used a breadboard to create a reset button but it isn’t doing anything.

I'd put the code here, but I don't have it. I actually did this a year or two ago, but I couldn't get the Pico to work again, so I gave up and just threw it in a cupboard and abandoned it. The code was probably something like:

```py
from machine import Pin, Timer
led = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)
timer = Timer()

def blink(timer):
    led.toggle()

timer.init(freq=2.5, mode=Timer.PERIODIC, callback=blink)
```

I just found this online as how to get the Pico to blink, but clearly I must have done something wrong because I can't get it to stop. Help!

Answer (score 1):

I know little about how MicroPython works on the Pico, but if you have somehow lost connection with the IDE, perhaps you could reload the MicroPython runtime as described at https://micropython.org/download/RPI_PICO/.

Hold your reset and BOOTSEL at the same time, then release reset while holding BOOTSEL, then release BOOTSEL.  If that does not work, then your reset button is incorrect - hold BOOTSEL whilst connecting the USB instead.

Once in bootloader mode, the board will mount as a mass storage device to which you can copy the MicroPython UF2 file.

Be aware that your code should be placed in  main.py, not boot.py.  Apparently boot.py runs before full runtime configuration, and may be why you lost connection with the development host.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's what a microcontroller is supposed to do. Since it has no operating system, all it can do is run the given program.
As long as the pico is connected to thonny, at least the repl runs forever.
But in general your code is the only thing the pico can do. That's why there is no exit() function in MicroPython - there is nothing it could exit to.
So your reset button can only restart your program.
If you want to stop the blinking LED, your code has to handle that. Use your button not as a reset button, but as a light switch. Something like

```
from machine import Pin
import time

led = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)
button = Pin(14, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)

is_light_on = True

led.value(is_light_on) # turn the LDE on

while True:
    if button.value():
        is_light_on  = not is_light_on # flip the switch
        led.value(is_light_on) # set the LED to the current state
        while button.value(): # wait until the button is released
          time.sleep(0.05) 
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

The basic structure of this code is a typical microcontroller code: first you have a setup phase, where you declare your pins, IO etc. and initialize them to whatever they shall do.
Then you have a "forever" loop that does the work and never exits.

Comment: But how do I get the code onto the Pico? Thorny won’t connect, and I can’t really do anything while the looping code is running, right?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 Nuke your pico:

check out: https://github.com/polhenarejos/pico-nuke

Step 2 Replace your main.py with some other/new script

Step 3 Go do something fun with your pico

Answer (score 0):

To end a timer in MicroPython, you may use the `.deinit()` function.

Here's an example variation of your code that blinks the LED 5 times using a `Timer`:

```py
from machine import Pin, Timer
led = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)
timer = Timer()
blink_counter = 0

def blink(timer):
    global blink_counter
    
    if blink_counter == 5:
        timer.deinit()
        return
    
    led.toggle()
    print(blink_counter)
        
    blink_counter += 1

timer.init(freq=2.5, mode=Timer.PERIODIC, callback=blink)
```

A `while True` loop checking a pin repeatedly is one way to handle button presses. However, using `irq` (which stands for interrupt), is a recommended solution as it doesn't clog up the main loop, alowing for the execution of other code (such as reading sensors or performing complex computations) and improves the Pico's performance.

Here's a modified code that blinks the LED and turns off the `Timer` after a press of a button handled by an `irq`:

```py
from machine import Pin, Timer

led = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)
button = Pin(0, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
timer = Timer()

def blink(timer):
    led.toggle()
    print("blink")

def button_pressed(pin):
    timer.deinit()
    print("button was pressed, blinking ended")

timer.init(freq=2.5, mode=Timer.PERIODIC, callback=blink)
button.irq(trigger=Pin.IRQ_FALLING, handler=button_pressed)
```

The code assumes a button is connected between Pin 0 and Pico's GND pin.

Please note that if the button interrupt is handled multiple times, buttons tend to bounce. Therefore, a filter, either via code implementation or a capacitor next to the button, is required for reliable button reading.

For further work with `Timer` or `IRQ` in MicroPython, I recommend having a look at:

https://www.upesy.com/blogs/tutorials/hardware-interrupts-rpi-pico-on-micropython

https://www.upesy.com/blogs/tutorials/timer-raspberry-pi-pico-with-micropython